# Find the period of the trigonometrics functions $\sin[\cos(x)]$ and $\cos[\sin(x)]$

Tags: trigonometry

So I need to find the period of these two trigonometric functions:

$$\cos[\sin(x)]$$
and
$$\sin[\cos(x)]$$

but algebraically and without using the graph of this functions.

So to be more clear, my question is: Is there any algebraic method or any mathematical trick I can use it to find the periods of these two trigonometric functions?' even  without the proof.

Like the period of $\cos(bx)$ is $2\pi/b$ directly without drawing the graph and without calculations.

Comment: Just take a stab at $\sin(\cos( x+2\pi))$.

Comment: A function is periodic if $f(x)=f(x+T)$ for some value of $T$

Comment: Simplify $\cos(\sin(x+\pi))$.

Comment: Look up "composition of periodic functions". This will give you some insight. Iff you don't find anything useful, I will see if I can write an answer about it sometime. [This is relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959139/if-f-and-g-are-periodic-functions-is-g-circ-f-periodic), but it doesn't show that $\pi$ is the period (rather, just that the composition is periodic).

Answer (score 5):

It is clear that $f : x \mapsto \cos(\sin(x))$ is periodic, since $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$ for every $x$. Let's find its period.

Let $T \in \mathbb{R}$. One has
\begin{align*} & \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad f(x+T)=f(x) \\
\Longleftrightarrow \quad & \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad \cos(\sin(x+T))=\cos(\sin(x))\\
\Longleftrightarrow \quad & \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad |\sin(x+T)|=|\sin(x)| \\
& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \textit{(because } \sin(x),\ \sin(x+T) \in [-1,1])\\
\Longleftrightarrow \quad & T \in \pi\mathbb{Z}\\
& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \textit{(because } |\sin| \textit{ is } \pi-\textit{periodic})\\
\end{align*}

So the period of $f$ is $\pi$.

Try the same approach with $x \longmapsto \sin(\cos(x))$.